# How to disable the complete UI of MSI installation. I have created installer in Visual studio 2019 using setup project for VSTO project office aadin

Tags: visual-studio, windows-installer, vsto

I am new to VSTO office addin, I have created VSTO project in VS 2019 for outlook addin.I have created installer in Visual studio 2019 using setup project for VSTO project outlook aadin.now I want to disable the GUI of MSI installation.
How to disable the complete UI of MSI installation?

Comment: The answer from Eugene is the right approach. You can suppress the GUI via command line switches. This is a built-in feature of MSI known to people tasked with deploying packages in corporate settings. Use this approach by documenting how to do this for your package to the people who need it. A special case is for WiX MSI files - they can be compiled to have no GUI at all. Generally not a good idea - except for testing scenarios where you want to do less clicking.

Answer (score 1):

There is no option to disable the whole UI in MSI by default. Instead, you may use a command line switch which allows running installers silently (without any UI interactions).

The proper way to install an MSI silently is via the `msiexec.exe` command line (the executable program that interprets packages and installs products):

```
msiexec.exe /i c:\setup.msi /QN /L*V "C:\Temp\msilog.log"
```

Where the parameters stand for:

- `/L*V "C:\Temp\msilog.log"` - verbose logging
- `/QN` - run completely silently
- `/i` - run install sequence

You can read more about possible command line parameters on the [Command-Line Options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/command-line-options) page.